# Android different resolutions problem

Tags: android, resolution

I have 9 (vertical) radio buttons and they are all showing in default resolution (320x480) without problems . But when I'm trying in resolution for Htc Tattoo (240x320) the last radio button is  hidden - there isn't space to be shown. How to make uniformly size ?

Comment: It would be good if you could edit the layout file into your question. That would enable us to give you a much clearer answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your layout is simply to big for the screen of the tatoo you could use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) to enable the user to scroll to the last button.

Try to not use an absolute layout and absolute px values. If you are using values like `layout_height="5px"` try to change this to `layout_height="5dip"` as described in the [supporting different screen resolutions guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) this will enable the os to scale your app to different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Let Android help you:

[Here's the guide to best practices on the Android site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: if you have read the guide you are linking you will see that computing a scale factor is nearly never necessary on android there are much better mechanisms to handle that.

Comment: Agreed, thought poster might want a quick fix, but edited my answer to just link to SDK guide.